# How do you remove old records from the BAMPrimaryImport TDDS_FailedTrackingData table?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

How can you remove old records from the **BAMPrimaryImport** TDDS_FailedTrackingData table?

... *not the TDDS_FailedTrackingData in the **BizTalkDTADb** database*

Our production system has 2+ million records in the `BAMPrimaryImport.dbo.TDDS_FailedTrackingData`, and the various BizTalk SQL Agent jobs are running fine, but these records are still there.

**UPDATE:** We sorted the issue that was generating the fails (fingers crossed), so there are no new records.

Comment: If I remember rightly, this means you have a problem that requires attention. Something is trying to write to BAM but is failing due to missing artefacts or some other tracking problem exists. It is safe to manually delete from this table (we do). I see that you are using BizTalk 2010, not sure if something similar will apply but there was a bug in earlier versions that didn't delete this data: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977289

Comment: @SuitedAces Thanks for the response. We sorted the issue that was generating the fails (fingers crossed), so there are no new records. I believe the Microsoft KB article refers to the TDDS_FailedTrackingData in the BizTalkDTADb database, rather than the one in BAMPrimaryImport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a case of manually deleting the records (`TRUNCATE TABLE` or `DELETE FROM`) ...

---

I've used Red Gate's SQL Search and looked for `TDDS_FailedTrackingData` throughout the database ...
*all objects and all databases*

Found 8 references in the entire system ... see below

Records are removed from the `[BizTalkDTADb].[dbo].[TDDS_FailedTrackingData]` in two stored procedures ...

- `[dtasp_CleanHMData]` does a `TRUNCATE TABLE`
- `[dtasp_PurgeTrackingDatabase_Internal]` does a `DELETE FROM` for 100 records at a time

However the `[BAMPrimaryImport]` database only has one stored procedure that has any mention of the `[BAMPrimaryImport].[dbo].[TDDS_FailedTrackingData]` table ...

- `[BAMPrimaryImport].[dbo].[TDDS_InsertFailedTrackingData]`
- and it just inserts records, with the addition of current date & time from GETUTCDATE()

Found lots of posts about clearing down the `[BizTalkDTADb]` table, but very few on clearing down the `[BAMPrimaryImport]`

This on [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/8df43060-e6f3-46d7-94fa-55f87ec35773/question-about-bamprimaryimportdbotddsfailedtrackingdata-table?forum=biztalkgeneral) from a BizTalk MVP

And this on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce8e7fc0-649c-47c1-8005-9769f900b928/delete-rows-from-table-tddsfailedtrackingdata-of-bamprimaryimport-db?forum=biztalkgeneral) from another BizTalk expert.

[image: SQL Search results for TDDS_FailedTrackingData]

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you as well:
http://www.codit.eu/blog/2014/07/03/maintaining-biztalk-bam-databases/

I'm not claiming this is an actual answer to your question, but it is about maintaining the BAM databases using NSVacuum.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sadly the blog post and the various linked posts are focussed on the actual BAM tables ... nothing about the TDDS_FailedTrackingData table  :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can manually perform a simple DELETE TSQL script :

```
DELETE FROM [BAMPrimaryImport].[dbo].[TDDS_FailedTrackingData]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ... I'd come to the same conclusion. Do you have any other knowledge about the missing "clean-up" functionality, or are you just answering how to remove records?  Also I'm not sure "DELETE FROM" would be the best option when we have 2.1+ million records, I think "TRUNCATE TABLE" is going to be better

Comment: I have no particular knowledge about this missing functionnality. I consider this table as a log table, which helps to identify some logging issues. A TRUNCATE statement will be faster, but you will loose the sequence. I think it is not a problem as well.